Socket.io when socket server send msg client socket.on is not trigger
I have implemented one-to-one chat using socket.io-client in React Native. I have two users, and they are messaging each other using the socket.emit event. One user sends a message to the other, but the other user does not receive the message because the socket.on method is not triggering.
The socket is connected properly, but I am not receiving the data sent by the other user.
Could you please suggest a solution?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
